# python выдаёт IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Программа должна преобразовать "The_Cat-Was-pippi" в "TheCatWasPippi" и "the_stealth_warrior" в "theStealthWarrior"
Но появляется ошибка:

````
  File "/workspace/default/tests.py", line 5, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(to_camel_case(''), '', "An empty string was provided but not returned")
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 3, in to_camel_case
    if text[0].isupper():
IndexError: string index out of range ```


#Код
def to_camel_case(text):
    text = text.replace('-', ' ').replace('_', ' ')
    if text[0].isupper():
        return text.title().replace(' ', '')
    elif text=='':
        return ""
    else:
        text = text.title().replace(' ', '')
        return text.replace(text[0], text[0].lower(), 1)
    

print(to_camel_case('The_Cat-Was-pippi'))
print(to_camel_case('the_stealth_warrior'))
````

Comment: нормально в PyCharm этот код отрабатывает

Comment: @Сергей, `print(to_camel_case(''))` это должно уронить код :)

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, ясно. Я проверяю тот тест, что дает автор. Если тест он тут пишет один, а у себя запускает другой, я не трачу на это время, так как пока это не на "автомате" ловится:-) Автору повезло, что вы посмотрели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть проверка на пустую строку `text==''`, но почему-то проверяете после того как было обращение к ее элементам `text[0]` (кст лучше проверять строки, и не только, через булевые проверки, например через `not`).

Немного переписал код

Пример:

```
def to_camel_case(text: str) -> str:
    if not text:
        return ''

    text = text.replace('-', ' ').replace('_', ' ')
    if text[0].isupper():
        return text.title().replace(' ', '')
    
    text = text.title().replace(' ', '')
    return text.replace(text[0], text[0].lower(), 1)
```

**UPD.** без дублирования кода:

```
def to_camel_case(text: str) -> str:
    if not text:
        return ''

    first_char_is_lower = text[0].islower()

    text = text.replace('-', ' ').replace('_', ' ')
    text = text.title().replace(' ', '')
    if first_char_is_lower:
        text = text[0].lower() + text[1:]

    return text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_camel_case(text):
    txt = text.replace('_', '-').split('-')
    return ''.join([i.capitalize() for i in txt])


print(to_camel_case('The_Cat-Was-pippi'))
print(to_camel_case('the_stealth_warrior'))

TheCatWasPippi
TheStealthWarrior
```

Comment: По условию задачи "the_stealth_warrior" станет "theStealthWarrior", а у вас "TheStealthWarrior" :)